# Add element before scroll position, and not affect current scroll / view

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, twitter-client

I’m trying to achieve the behaviour – for example – the Twitter Mac client:

I got a box I can scroll in (overflow Y, fixed height),  and I got several blocks inside. I want to add a new block before all others, but make it invisible to the user: so when there’s a new block added before, user have to scroll to the top to view it.

How would you achieve this? (JS powered of course, but must be touch-devices ready, and iP* do not run JS while scrolling).

Thanks!

Comment: You could try scrolling down immediately after inserting the element, by an amount equal to the height of the new element added?

Comment: I was indeed thinking about adding and scroll the height of inserted element, but it sometimes means a visible flash (kill the scroll when user is scrolling)

Comment: Yeah, there might be a small flash, you could make the page overflow:hidden with the new scroll position and that might make take the flash away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried out changing the scrollTop after the element is added, and it seems to work fine on Chrome. You would have to check it out in other browsers.

```
$(document).scrollTop($(document).scrollTop() + elmHeight);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ub5BU/

Comment: I tried something like that, and this is so far the best solution I found. But there's still some problems with mouses intertia (Mac mouses), and they are strange behaviours with touch devices…
Cf. http://jsfiddle.net/ub5BU/1/